# Connecting to multiple networks - one existing

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to use docker-compose for the first time. I would like my container to be connected to two networks, one that is defined in the docker-compose file and one that already exists but I am struggling to get this to work.

I have found these [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#use-a-pre-existing-network) and ended up with the below config:

```
haproxy:
        container_name: haproxy
        links:
            - 'mysql1:mysql1cl'
            - 'mysql2:mysql2cl'
        volumes:
            - '/docker-data/configs/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:ro'
        ports:
            - '33060:3306'
            - '38080:8080'
        image: 'haproxy:latest'
        networks:
            - athenanet
            - external:
                name: bridge
```

But this is giving me the following error:

```
services.haproxy.networks contains {"external": "bridge"}, which is an invalid type, it should be a string
```

I therefore tried using the default network as is, and ended up with the below config:

```
haproxy:
        container_name: haproxy
        links:
            - 'mysql1:mysql1cl'
            - 'mysql2:mysql2cl'
        volumes:
            - '/docker-data/configs/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:ro'
        ports:
            - '33060:3306'
            - '38080:8080'
        image: 'haproxy:latest'
        networks:
            - athenanet
            - bridge
```

But then I end up with the following error:

```
ERROR: Service "haproxy" uses an undefined network "bridge"
```

Does someone have the proper config to connect both to a defined network and an existing network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. You have to define your external network on the top level of the Compose file, not under the service. So put this to the root of the compose file:

```
networks:
  mynetwork:
    external:
      name: my-pre-existing-network-name
```

Then under your haproxy service use the network:

```
haproxy:
        ...
        networks:
            - mynetwork
```

You can check the docs here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external-1.

Comment: Awesome - worked like a charm! Thank you very much Mark.

Answer (score 0):

I see several things:

According to your first docker-compose file, you have to differenciate between network definition and usage inside docker-compose service.
Inside docker-compose service (section haproxy:), you should only use docker-network name = athenanet in your case.
All atributes such as external, have to be defined in networks: section, outside sevice section. Just have a look to this:

```
haproxy:
  container_name: haproxy
  links:
    - 'mysql1:mysql1cl'
    - 'mysql2:mysql2cl'
  volumes:
    - '/docker-data/configs/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:ro'
  ports:
    - '33060:3306'
    - '38080:8080'
  image: 'haproxy:latest'
  networks:
    - athenanet

networks:
  athenanet:
    external:
      name: <external-docker-network-name>
```

Second, is highly recommended not to use reserved keywords for docker network names. In your second docker-compose, you're trying to work with two networks: athenanet and bridge, while bridge is one of possible types as you can see in docker documentation:

https://docs.docker.com/network/